# Intercept the change from portrait to landscape mode during app execution

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi I don't understand how to intercept if the user rotate the phone in from portarait to landscape or from landscape to portrait. I know that there are few methods:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

but If I put this method in AppDelegate.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Pls accept some answers if u want people to help you

Answer (score 2):

Those are not `UIApplicationDelegate` methods, so your AppDelegate won't receive them.

They're implemented in `UIViewController` and you can override them in one of your view controllers (subclasses of `UIViewController`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in any or all of the view controllers that u are using. That will intercept the change for that particular view controller. Those are `UIViewController` delegates and are not accessible by `appDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement these delegate methods into your viewcontroller then whenever your view controller rotates. You will get response in respective delegtes.

Answer (score 0):

Andrea you can implement those methods in your viewcontroller and your view controller  is responsible to call those delegate methods

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {}
    else {}
}
```

Comment: Pls edit your answers and use code formatting. Its a special feature of SO